# Cassandra sstable filename format

Tags: cassandra

Does anyone know what the character/letter "f" in the filename stands for? Is it arbitrary or does it have some meaning

```
test-f-9-Data.db
test-f-9-Filter.db
test-f-9-Index.db
test-f-9-Statistics.db
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a version number - version f is the current SSTable format, I think.

See http://www.mail-archive.com/commits@cassandra.apache.org/msg15060.html